# About sbrk() and malloc()

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, sbrk

I've read the linux manual about sbrk() thoroughly:

> sbrk() changes the location of the program break, which defines the end
>   of the process's data segment (i.e., the program break is the first
>   location after the end of the uninitialized data segment).

And I do know that user space memory's organization is like the following:
[image]

The problem is:
***When I call sbrk(1), why does it say I am increasing the size of heap? As the manual says, I am changing the end position of "data segment & bss". So, what increases should be the size of data segment & bss, right?***

Comment: Hint: Which end of your diagram corresponds to higher (numerically greater) addresses, and which end to lower addresses?  Which way does the stack grow?  Which way does the heap grow?

Comment: In practice, your picture is very naive and does not really show what is happening. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data and bss segments are a fixed size.  The space allocated to the process after the end of those segments is therefore not a part of those segments; it is merely contiguous with them.  And that space is called the heap space and is used for dynamic memory allocation.

If you want to regard it as 'extending the data/bss segment', that's fine too.  It won't make any difference to the behaviour of the program, or the space that's allocated, or anything.

The manual page on Mac OS X indicates you really shouldn't be using them very much:

> **The brk and sbrk functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the advent of virtual memory management.** The `brk()` function sets the break or lowest address of a process's data segment (uninitialized data) to `addr` (immediately above bss).  Data addressing is restricted between `addr` and the lowest stack pointer to the stack segment.  Memory is allocated by `brk` in page size pieces; if `addr` is not evenly divisible by the system page size, it is increased to the next page boundary.
>
> The current value of the program break is reliably returned by `sbrk(0)` (see also *end(3)*). The *getrlimit(2)* system call may be used to determine the maximum permissible size of the data segment; it will not be possible to set the break beyond the `rlim_max` value returned from a call to `getrlimit`, e.g.  `etext + rlp->rlim_max` (see *end(3)* for the definition of `etext`).

It is mildly exasperating that I can't find a manual page for *end(3)*, despite the pointers to look at it.  Even this (slightly old) manual page for [`sbrk()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sbrk.2.html) does not have a link for it.

Comment: Then, " the program break is the first location after the end of the uninitialized data segment" given by the manual is quite confusing.... Because uninitialized data segment refers to end of bss, right?

Comment: Here is the one from FreeBSD: [`end(3)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=end&sektion=3).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that today [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) is rarely used. Most `malloc` implementations are using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) -at least for large allocations- to acquire a memory segment (and `munmap` to release it). Quite often, `free` simply marks a memory zone to be reusable by some future `malloc`  (and does not release any memory to the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)).

<sup>(so practically, the heap of a modern linux process is made of *several* segments, so is more subtle than your picture; and multi-threaded processes have one stack per [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29))</sup>

Use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), notably `/proc/self/maps`  and `/proc/$pid/maps`, to understand the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). Try first to understand the output of `cat /proc/self/maps` (showing the address space of that `cat` command) and of `cat /proc/$$/maps` (showing the address space of your shell). Try also to look at the `maps` pseudo-file for your web browser (e.g. `cat /proc/$(pidof firefox)/maps` or `cat /proc/$(pidof iceweasel)/maps` etc...); I have more than a thousand lines (so process segments) in it.

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) done by a given command or process.

Take advantage that on Linux most (and probably all) [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementations are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code. The source code of [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) is quite easy to read.

Read also about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) & [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html), and the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) book then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)