# Creating a buffer manually with things like `brk` and `mmap`

Tags: linux, malloc, nasm

How would I go about making my very own `malloc` implementation in assembler (NASM, to be specific)? Google has been inconclusive on a `malloc` workaround. `mmap` has something to do with files (according to it's manual) and `brk` expands the space pointers refer to (I think), though I don't have a pointer in the first place. Clarity would be much appreciated.

I'm using NASM on x64 Linux

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In malloc, why use brk at all? Why not just use mmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768549/in-malloc-why-use-brk-at-all-why-not-just-use-mmap)

Comment: I would start with studying existing `malloc` implementations.