# segmentation fault when calling brk() and printf()

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, brk

> Note: `sys_brk` returns the `program break` while `brk()` returns 0 or -1.（According to manual brk(2), NOTES）

The following code can pass.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
    long beg_break = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);//get current program break.
    
    long mid_break =  syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break + 100);
    
    long end_break = syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break);//set the program break back
}
```

But there will be a segmentation fault at the line `syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break)` if I try to print them：

( *My question is at the end.*)

```c
long beg_break = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);
printf ("%#lX\n", beg_break);

long mid_break =  syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break + 100);
printf ("%#lX\n", mid_break);

long end_break = syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break);
printf ("%#lX\n", end_break);
```

Output:

```c
0X557E46CDE000
0X557E46CDE064
Segementation fault
```

It's not accendital, I have tried many times on different PCs, also the experiments below:

1. using `stderr` instead of `stdout`, it works.

```c
long beg_break = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);
fprintf (stderr, "%#lX\n", beg_break);

long new_break =  syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break + 100);
fprintf (stderr, "%#lX\n", new_break);

long end_break = syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break);
fprintf (stderr, "%#lX\n", end_break);
```

2. not using `printf()` between `brk()`, it works.

```c
long beg_break = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);
long mid_break =  syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break + 100);
long end_break = syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break);

printf ("%#lX\n", beg_break);
printf ("%#lX\n", mid_break);
printf ("%#lX\n", end_break);
```

3. disable buffering of stdout, it works.

```c
setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
long beg_break = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);
printf ("%#lX\n", beg_break);

long mid_break =  syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break + 100);
printf ("%#lX\n", mid_break);

long end_break = syscall (SYS_brk, beg_break);
printf ("%#lX\n", end_break);
```

So I guess it results from `printf()` calling `malloc()`, which bases on `brk()`:

```c
long beg = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);
printf ("hello world %d\n", 123);
long end = syscall (SYS_brk, 0);

printf ("%#lX\n", beg);
printf ("%#lX\n", end);
```

The output:

```c
hello world 123
0X56501B6F0000
0X56501B711000
```

It seems that I should avoid using C library with `brk()`:

Since `brk()` doesn't write/read the memory on heap, why `brk()`, instead of `printf()`, results in the segmentation fault ?

Comment: Why don't you use [`sbrk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) instead?

Comment: Also, what is the actual and original problem you need to solve? What is the reason you want to use `sbrk`? What problem is it supposed to solve? You are aware of that it has been marked as legacy and doesn't even exist in POSIX?

Comment: Per the [Linux `brk()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html#NOTES): "Avoid using `brk()` and `sbrk()`: the `malloc(3)` memory allocation package is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory."  And see [**In malloc, why use brk at all? Why not just use mmap?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768549/in-malloc-why-use-brk-at-all-why-not-just-use-mmap).  Note what that title states:  `malloc()` uses `[s]brk()` internally for heap memory.  When you call `brk()`, you, umm, *break* `malloc()`.  And `printf()` uses `malloc()` internally...

Comment: I will bet a cookie. that it's actually crashing on the third call to printf. Printf may (but is not required to) call malloc internally.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm tring to control another process by `ptrace()`. It's easy to invoke system call. But I'm not sure about C library.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm trying to control another to allocate memory by `ptrace()`. I don't how to invoke `malloc()` or `sbrk()` by `ptrace()`, because they are not system calls.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It seems that `mmap()` is more complex than `brk()`. So I haven't tried it.

Comment: `ptrace` exists for debuggers and *only* for debuggers. Are you writing a debugger?

Comment: @zwol I use it to Intercept system calls.

Comment: @barbyQAQ That is not an answer to the question I asked you.